# TxReceipt Status:Fail what should i do?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

[image]

TxReceipt Status:Fail  what should i do ?
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ed9f4f76312a7141975d29f40e042fecc8a9bc7f380e3a45156ddca7590750b

Comment: did you end up getting an answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20319)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your transaction failed due to this line in the smart contract's [source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xedab973d01970f6f83962fe3aaae818f1cd13487#code):

```
require(msg.value >= 1 ether);
```

Your transaction only sent 0.1 ether, and apparently that's not allowed.

Comment: so how can i get my eht back ?

Comment: Your ether never went anywhere. Failed transactions have no effect, but you do still have to pay for gas, so you spent about 0.003 ether (~$3.46 USD) for this failed transaction. Nothing else happened.

Comment: when i get it ? i mean when add the eth in my eth wallet ? or how long time wait for that my eth get back in my wallet ? can u please tell me

Comment: The ether (except the gas cost) never left your account. So you don't have to wait at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this . but my coinbase account shown previous balance , still now i did not get that ETH . thats why i ask that question ..

Comment: Well then you'll need to ask Coinbase.

Comment: Also, it seems like you were trying to buy tokens using a Coinbase account. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28651/can-i-receive-erc20-tokens-on-my-address-hosted-on-coinbase for why that may lead to you losing those tokens forever.